# Alphabet array in C has an extra '@' at the end

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to build two string arrays by using the letters' corresponding ASCII codes - one with lowercase alphabet letters and one with uppercase.

```
char lc['z' - 'a'];
for(int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ ) {
    lc[i - 'a'] = i ;
}

printf("%s", lc);

char uc['Z' - 'A'];
for(int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ ) {
    uc[i - 'A'] = i ;
}

printf("\n%s", uc);
```

The output I get is correct, except that for both tables, there's an extra @ symbol at the end and I have no idea why. If I change the loop condition to i < 'Z' instead, it cuts off the z/Z, not the @, so I suspect it might have something to do with the '\0' symbol ending string arrays?

Comment: `'z'-'a'` equals to `25`. So you have several UBs here. And a string has to be null-terminated to print it with `printf`...

Comment: `@` corresponds to 64 in decimal number, so make sure if this is not the reason, because coincidentally, `@` is one position before capital letter `A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct: You need to end the strings off with a '\0' since `printf`(and pretty much every other string handling function in C) expects them like this. Also you would need one more element in the array for the whole alphabet. You code should be:

```
char lc['z' - 'a' + 2];
for(int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ ) {
    lc[i - 'a'] = i ;
}

lc['z' - 'a' + 1] = '\0';

printf("%s", lc);

char uc['Z' - 'A' + 2];
for(int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ ) {
    uc[i - 'A'] = i ;
}

uc['Z' - 'A' + 1] = '\0';

printf("\n%s", uc);
```

If you are wondering the '@' is probably just a random value in memory after the array and since it hasn't reached '\0' `printf` continues printing.